Can I use K-means clustering to compare change across two satellite images
I want to quanity the change in two satellite images that have the same spatial extent - can I define the clusters by calculating k-means clusters for both images stacked together and then apply the clusters to each image individually so the categories remain the same?
I can't find any literature directly relating to this so wondering if it is a viable method.

hi please read How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?
